How do I tell Postgres to only scan the newest values in this query?
I have a big table with sensor measurements that has this structure:
create table measurements (
  sensor_id    varchar(50)      not null,
  timestamp    timestamptz      not null,
  value        decimal(10, 6)   not null,
  primary key (sensor_id, timestamp)
)

It contains measurements from sensors (rain gauges, but that doesn't really matter) taken at 5 minute intervals. Sensor values can be 0 or positive, but not negative. Currently the dataset goes back a bit more than one year, but it should be able to handle years of data.
I want to retrieve the most recent measurements per sensor for further analysis, such that I get at least two weeks worth of measurements, and the set of measurements should contain at least 100 non-zero values. The query I used is this:
select *
from (
    select sensor_id, timestamp, "value",
      sum(cast("value" > 0 as INT)) over w as cum_nonzero_measurements,
      row_number() over w as cum_measurements,
      first_value(timestamp) over w - timestamp as age
    from measurements
    window w as (partition by sensor_id order by timestamp desc)
    ) windowed
where (cum_nonzero_measurements <= 100 or age < interval '2 weeks' )
  and sensor_id in ($1)
order by sensor_id, timestamp desc

This query only needs the most recent N measurements for a sensor, although N can vary. The smart way to execute such a query would be to start reading from the most recent value going backward in time. However Postgresql doesn't realize the query can be executed in that way, and insists on loading all measurements for the given sensor_ids, doing a window aggregation over all rows, and only then filtering out most of the rows to get the result.
I tried with different indices, which helps it retrieve all rows for the requested sensors more quickly, but whatever I do Postgres keeps loading all rows for the sensors in question. Currently the performance is acceptable, but that doesn't scale very well if the dataset grows.
Is there any way to convince Postgres that it doesn't need to load all the rows, only the most recent ones?

Try to put the WHERE condition inside the subquery. You won't get your window function for the first few rows though.

@LaurenzAlbe The where condition depends on the window aggregation, so it can't go inside the subquery. Except for the sensor_id condition, but Postgres already pushes that down to the subquery by itself.

Offtopic: extract(epoch from age) < 60*60*24*14 /*two weeks*/ can be rewritten as age < INTERVAL '2 weeks'

@FrankHeikens indeed. I had already changed that in the project, but not here.

It's the classic "Top-N by category" problem, with a bit of a plot twist.
Fastest solution will probably be a lateral join. This allows executing a join with a dependent subquery.
If you have a separate table listing the sensor_ids, it is very simple. The idea is exactly what you wrote in your question: for each sensor_id, start reading from the most recent value going backward in time.
Here's a quick test case which gets the most recent 100 values for all sensors:
create unlogged table measurements (
  sensor_id    int       not null,
  timestamp    float       not null,
  value        decimal(10, 6)   not null,
  primary key (sensor_id, timestamp)
);

insert into measurements 
select random()*100, n, case when random()>0.5 then random() else 0 end 
from generate_series( 1, 1000000 ) n;

vacuum analyze measurements;

CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE sensors AS SELECT sensor_id FROM measurements GROUP BY sensor_id;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM sensors s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM measurements m WHERE m.sensor_id = s.sensor_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 200) top;

It does a nested loop on sensors, then index scan backwards on measurements. To get only specific sensors:
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM measurements m WHERE m.sensor_id = s.column1 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 100) top;

Contrary to a regular join, the table expression in the lateral join is dependent on s.column1 from previous tables. It is re-evaluated for each row from VALUES() and the limit is applied. This is what makes it work. Without LATERAL, the table expression in the join would only be applied once, so the LIMIT would only be applied once, instead of per sensor which is what you want.
Rather than VALUES() you can also put the sensor_id's in an array and unnest() it.
However, that only gives the 100 most recent values, which is not what you want! Here's a suggestion:
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) s
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM measurements m WHERE m.sensor_id = s.column1 AND value>0 ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 99) first
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM measurements m WHERE m.sensor_id = s.column1 AND timestamp >= first.timestamp ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 200) top;

The first lateral join has "value>0" in the WHERE condition so it only considers these rows. Thanks to the limit/offset, it skips 99 rows going backward in time, then grabs the timestamp for this row, which is used as a starting point for the second lateral join which simply returns all rows posterior to this timestamp.
In both cases, it will use the index, so it should not read rows far into the past and therefore should not slow down as table size increases.

This was indeed the trick to (mostly) solving my issue. Postgres still does not understand (at the planner level) that it should search starting with the most recent values, but using a limit that is applied per sensor_id in the lateral join we can tell it that, and with the right index it will only read the rows up to the limit.

In my query there is no fixed limit of how many values are necessary, that depends on the data. But based on the distribution of my data I can set a limit that will be sufficient to include all needed rows in practice. The query will still read more data than necessary, but not nearly the whole dataset, and that gives enough performance.

An additional benefit of join lateral is that Postgres can then do an efficient lookup based on one sensor_id in the index. Doing an efficient lookup of multiple discontinuous keys is not implemented in Postgres (see 'index skip scan'), so with multiple sensor_id's it will often fall back to a different access method that reads all data for the selected stations.

I'm glad it helps! You mean it still doesn't do "index scan backwards" in the lateral join? What version do you have? A very long time ago I think you had to specify all the index columns in the order by, and with the same ACS/DESC, to get index scan backwards. I think this was improved a while ago. Anyway, LATERAL is a nice replacement for index skip scan IMO.

You could also try a database specifically optimized for time series, for example Clickhouse. It has rather large tradeoffs, it's really not meant to delete and update, it's not designed for small transaction processing AT ALL, however it compresses my data by a factor of about 10 and processes billions of rows per second in aggregates...

It does an index scan backward all right. Without a limit, it index scans backward all the values for the given station_ids, and then filters out most of them again. Lateral is a nice feature and I can see legitimate uses for it, but I'd rather have the database execute the query in a sensible way without needing such tricks.
I don't know Clickhouse but I don't see a need for that right now, using JOIN LATERAL with an index scan works just fine (though it is a bit hacky).

Tot be fair, doing an index scan for each sensor_id was already a significant improvement over the join it was doing without 'lateral'

One issue is, it's not the same query, since the one with the lateral join has a hard LIMIT and the windowed one does not. Even if pg could do index skip scan, it would have to estimate that the number of non-zero rows in the requested time interval is large enough so the backwards index scan will be faster... That requires a lot of statistical knowledge about the data...

That is exactly the point of this question. PG has the basic statistics it needs (a large majority of the measurements are 0, there are no negative values, though adding an abs() in there doesn't make a difference). Any sane estimate on the distribution of the zeros would make an index scan be faster. But it just seems that the mathematical reasoning w.r.t. this window function isn't implemented. So my question was if there's any way to tell PG. E.g. something similar to extended statistics. It seems the answer is 'no', but the lateral join with a limit is a good alternative.

Yeah I don't think it's implemented for window functions.

In summary, the answer appears to be a combination of bobflux's answer and the comments there. Postgres' query planner (as of at least PG version 14, but AFAIK also version 17) is not currently smart enough to handle this and Postgres does not offer a way to inform the planner. But using a JOIN LATERAL with a LIMIT in the subquery does allow limiting Postgres to only reading the newest values from disk. That workaround is thus limited to queries that can be changed to use JOIN LATERAL and for which a sensible limit can be set.
